# Как задать целые числа с клавиатуры и вывести сумму четных на экран?

Tags: python

Нужно написать скрипт, который считывает с клавиатуры числа, складывает только четные и выводит результат на экран.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не считает?

```
a = int(input())
sum = 0
if a % 2 == 0:
    sum += a
    print(sum)
```

---

Выдает ошибку:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2 3 4 6'

Comment: `sum(filter(lambda e: e % 2 == 0, map(int, input().split())))`. У Вас не считает потому что Вы читаете строку `2 4 6 8`, и превращаете ее в int..., надо разделить сначала строку на числа. Либо `sum(map(lambda x: int(x) if int(x) % 2 == 0 else 0, input().split()))`

Comment: @entithat Спасибо. Понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = map(int, input().split())
sum = 0

for v in a:
    if not v % 2:
        sum = sum + v
        
print(sum)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/7utSwB

```
print(sum(x for x in map(int, input().split()) if not x % 2))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]